# Nearest point to a real algebraic set

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computational-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a compact bounded real algebraic (eventually: or analytic or semialgebraic or semianalytic set) $V \subset \mathbb R^3$ and a point $x\in\mathbb R^3 \setminus V$. How much do we know about finding the nearest point (using Euclidean distance) in $V$ to $x$? There are numerical approximation algorithms that work for any compact set in $\mathbb R^3$, for instance one could discreticize $V$ into points and then try some sort of nearest point search algorithm (using brute force search or kd-tree algorithm). But does $V$ having algebraic or analytic property help in finding an even faster algorithm (even if it is a numerical approximation) for this problem?

Comment: In the algebraic case one could try Lagrange multipliers :-)

Comment: See the recent preprint ``Euclidean distance degree of an algebraic variety", http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.0049.pdf